# Double integral of $\text{sin}(x)\text{cos}(y)$ bounded by $y=0$, $y=1-x$, $y=1+x$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

After simplifying the bounds, I obtained intervals of:

$$ 0 \leq y \leq 1$$ and $$y-1\leq x\leq 1-y$$

So the double integral becomes

$$\int_0^1\int_{y-1}^{1-y}\text{sin}(x)\text{cos}(y) dxdy=\int_0^1-\text{cos}(1-y)\text{cos}(y)-[-\text{cos}(y-1)\text{cos}(y)]dy$$

But $\cos(1-y)=\cos(y-1)$, So

$$\int_0^1-\text{cos}(y-1)\text{cos}(y)+\text{cos}(y-1)\text{cos}(y)dy = \int_0^1 0   dy = 0$$

Is this fine?

Comment: Yes, why did you think there is something wrong? Note that there is a tag of [proof-verification]

Comment: Because your region is symmetric about $x = 0$, and the function you are integrating is odd in $x$ (i.e. $f(-x, y) = -f(x,y)$), the integration has to be $0$. So your result is exactly what is expected.